# File size after storing as SQL image and transfering as base 64 string

Tags: c#, soap, blob, filesize, microsoft-dynamics

In our situation we store a file in a SQL database using Microsoft Dynamics NAV. Afterwards we take this blob/image data, convert it to a base64 string, transfer it over a SOAP service and save it as a file again. The resulting file is always much larger than the original. The file sizes seem to follow a distinct pattern of a factor of 2. 120KB, 248KB, 504KB, 1016KB, 2040KB, etc..

Example:
Storing a 23.669.715 byte file results in a 33.546.240 byte file after following this route.

C# code to save the file:

```
string fileData = string.Empty;
WebshopMgt webService = Helpers.WebServices.GetWebshopService();

try
{
    webService.GetDocumentData(navDocument.IntegrationID, ref fileData);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(String.Format("Error retrieving document data for NAV Document '{0}'.",     navDocument.IntegrationID), ex);
    return Status.SetStatus(navDocument.IntegrationID, syncId, SyncStatus.Failed, ex.Message);
}

try
{
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData);
    FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filePath);
    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fileStream.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(String.Format("Error saving document data for NAV Document '{0}'.", navDocument.IntegrationID), ex);
    return Status.SetStatus(navDocument.IntegrationID, syncId, SyncStatus.Failed, ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This code [looks OK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so the problem likely is in the storing or retrieving of the data.

Comment: While debugging I do see a pattern. All strings are padded with lots of 'A's. Some strings have tens of thousands of A's at the end. All ending in A==.

Comment: Given `A = 0` in almost all base 64 implementations, somewhere you're not saving the content length but the actual entire buffer. Say you're using a buffer of 1024 bytes and your content is only 1 byte long, it seems to be saving 1023 `0`'s.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested;
I was converting the file data to base64 using the GetBuffer method on a MemoryStream. Turns out that also gives you all allocated memory space, including unused bytes. Using the **ToArray** method returns only the data itself.